# JavaScript/HTML/CSS Halftone Lines Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am trying to find a library/API to convert an image and add an Halftone effect with lines, just as this image.

[image].

The original image is just a koala, example of this use was taken from [photocarver](https://store.photocarver.com/en/photorelief.html)

Basically i want to develop a web app that allows users to submit any image/photo and then apply this effect only, as a preview, and then they can submit for printing.

I just want to implement the same functionality as the one in [photocarver](https://store.photocarver.com/en/photorelief.html), but i only care about the image upload and apply the effect.

The only problem i have is that i cannot find any library/API that allows me to apply this effect, i would like it to be through JavaScript. I have found 2 ways of applying this filter but it uses only dots and the effect isn't the desired one.

**Questions**

1. Is there any library or API that already allows me to do this ? I have looked everywhere on GitHub, codepen and found nothing.
2. I thought about implementing my own module for this but is it required to have a solid knowhow about photo effects and pixel manipulation in order to implement my own ? I have experience with JS but i understand nothing about photography/effects.
3. Can i use the source code of the site that i gave above (where i got this image example) ? I tried to look at their code but i couldn't see how to take only the parts that i need in order to use on my own.
4. I have an .exe that allows me to do exactly this but it is UI based. Is there any way to spawn the process through JavaScript and apply effect programatically ? I think not, because it was problably develop with .NET framework and i do not know of a way to do this using JS. The app isn't even a DLL that i could use for API calls.
5. About implementing my own, has i have seen that there is no NPM module for this i'm also thinking about making one, could someone provide a guideline ? I basically just need the algorithm to apply to each image file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I try to search many solution, I reference this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/yckart/h00Lp4x8/), and write this [code](https://codepen.io/hexschool/pen/povbJZR) for you, if you want to set line border and gutter, check js line 51.

### JS

```
function drawLine(imageData){
  // settings variable
  let _width = imageData.width;
  let _height = imageData.height;
  let lineWidth = 4;
  let lineGutter = 7;
  for(let i = 0; _height>i;i+=lineGutter){
    console.log(i)
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, i);
    context.lineTo(_width, i);
    context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    context.stroke();
  }
}
```